# What is the opposite of "eschatology"?

Tags: antonyms, greek

Eschatology is the <strike>study or philosophy of</strike> formation of ideas about the end of things, apparently derived from the Greek ἔσχατος meaning "last" and -λογία meaning "study of".

What is the word for "the formation of ideas about the beginning of things?

Edit: I've accepted "cosmogony" as the answer, but I also really liked "protology". Thanks for your thoughts, everyone!

Comment: Hm... that might be the right word. I had always associated cosmology with "the beginning of outer space" but I suppose it also refers to "the beginning of things".

Comment: "The Cosmos is all that is or was or ever will be." – Carl Sagan

Comment: The most common Greek-based word that etymologically means ‘the study of origin(-related things)’ is **archaeology**, but that of course has a rather more common meaning that renders it unsuitable. There is the rather obscure **archology**, which does mean ‘the study of the origin of things’, but I suspect most people won’t know it and will just read it as a typo for _archaeology_ anyway.

Comment: Vote NOT to close because of usefulness of the answers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*Eschatology* has to do more with the "end of *humankind*" specifically than the "end of *things*". So, if *[Eschatology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eschatology)* is concerned with the final events of history, or the ultimate destiny of humanity, then **[Anthropogeny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropogeny)** is concerned with **study of human origins.**

Anthropogeny comes from Greek *anthropo-* (human) + Greek *-geny* (birth, origin).

But, if you want to take it in more general sense i.e. "final events of history", as [history](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/history)<sup>1</sup> can be of humans, earth, or cosmos, then it is **[Cosmogony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmogony)**.

> The word comes from the Koine Greek κοσμογονία (from κόσμος "cosmos, the world") and the root of γί(γ)νομαι / γέγονα ("come into a new state of being"). In astronomy, cosmogony refers to the study of the origin of particular astrophysical objects or systems, and is most commonly used in reference to ***the origin of the Universe, the Solar System, or the Earth–Moon system***.

And on the theological side, you can consider [Theogony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theogony): "the genealogy or birth of the gods."

---

<sub>1. 2nd definition of history according to Oxford Dictionary: The whole series of past events connected with a particular person or **thing**.</sub>

Comment: ἄνθρωπος does not mean _study of man_ but _man._
genies and gonies are not studies.  the study-of bit comes from λόγος.

Comment: @Toothrot so then would it be anthropogenology?

Comment: Early qualification with *if* makes the answer precarious! See other answers for other points of view.

Comment: In any case, the OP ought to have shown background effort first.

Comment: @HotelCalifornia, I think you mean anthropogenealogy.

Comment: @Toothrot I considered that, but then also considered that genealogy is potentially a different field altogether? Guess it goes to show that I should go with my gut more often

Comment: @HotelCalifornia is "anthropogenology" established field of study? or do it even exist?

Comment: @Toothrot Can you provide proper link to where I can define definition for **anthropogenealogy?** or some sort of citation?

Comment: @Toothrot In general, yes, ‘study of X’ is represented by _-(o)logy_. But that doesn’t change the fact that _anthropogeny_ **is** the study of the origin of humankind. It does not mean the origin of humankind (though [_anthropogenesis_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anthropogenesis) is), but the study of it. The word was not coined with strict adherence to the individual meanings of its constituents, but it was coined, and it now means what it means, not what its individual parts mean historically.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I was primarily referring to the indisputably
erroneous claim that _anthropo-_ should mean _study of humans._ But,
also, according to the OED, your sense of _anthropogeny_ is a derived
sense, not the only and not the primary sense; the primary sense is what
one would expect it to be.  I did not (mean to) dispute that there is a
derived sense, only the answerer's imprecise dealing with etymology.

Comment: @Ubihatt, I did not claim that this was a word in use.  I say only that,
_if_ one is to coin it, this is the form it must take.  But I would also
dispute the notion that a word does not exist unless it can be found in
a dictionary.

Comment: @Toothrot Ah, I had missed that it said ‘study of’ in the translations of the individual parts in the answer. I’ve edited that out, because that is indeed undoubtedly incorrect. You’re right the OED says it refers both to the origins and to their study, and some of the citations do appear to lean more towards the former than the latter; but I think overall, that’s a far rarer usage – or at least it is in my experience.

Answer (score 19):

Where *eschatos* means *last*, *protos* means *first*, so the word is ***[protology](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/protology)***.

> **Protology**
>
> *noun*
>
> The study or science of origins.

Comment: Current usage of the word _eschatology_ is related to **religions**, so a **science** is probably not the desired answer here. The question asked was primary to oppose ending with beginning, but likely keeping it in the registry of theist concepts.

Comment: @Cœur 'Protology' can definitely be used in a religious context as a literal opposite of 'eschatology'. E.g. this book https://www.logos.com/product/24556/the-gospel-of-genesis-studies-in-protology-and-eschatology-2nd-ed

Comment: Not to be confused with _proctology_, which – ironically – is also the study of ends in a sense.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ...which is not far from _scatology_, the study of the effects of those ends.

Answer (score 9):

The word "**[eschatology](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/eschatology)**" is most often used in the theological sense. Similarly, the word "**genesis**" is frequently used in the theological sense.

However,
"**eschatology**" *(in a general sense)* of the word is the "study of last (or end) things". The **corresponding opposite** general term for the beginning (or origin) of anything would be "**[genesis](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/genesis)**". Therefore, the opposite of eschatology *(in a general sense)* would be "**genesis studies**" or "**the study of geneses**". This *general* definition being "the study of beginnings (geneses or [origins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/origin))".

Comment: You didn't take the leading step to 'geneology', which of course has quite a different meaning than expected from that step.

Answer (score 4):

There are already some good answers, but none mentions the first word which comes to my mind: **aetiology** (alternative spelling **etiology** is preferred by some people).

This is the study of the origins of things in terms of causation (etymologically, *the study of causes*). The noun can also be used in the sense of "origin story"; this meaning is common in medicine, and fairly common in theology.

See: [Wikipedia:Etiology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etiology).

American Heritage Dictionary:

> n. pl. e·ti·ol·o·gies also ae·ti·ol·o·gies
>
> 1. a. The study of causes or origins.
>      b. The branch of medicine that deals with the causes or origins of disease.
> 2. a. Assignment of a cause, an origin, or a reason for something.
>      b. The cause or origin of a disease or disorder as determined by medical diagnosis.

Comment: I've often used etiology in reference to creation myths, thus the opposite of eschatology, but I dunno if that's common usage. I think technically it's the antonym of teleology (study of purpose)